# Can we say Apple inherits from both Fruit and Seed classes?

Tags: object-oriented, inheritance

Given three classes Apple, Fruit and Seed ;

Apple is a kind of Fruit and it has Seed in it. With the knowledge of Apple Class uses directly or indirectly the properties of Fruit and Seed. Can we say Apple is inherited from Fruit and Seed ?

Comment: Animal, vegetable and mineral examples are seldom illuminating, because inheritance usually deals with more abstract concepts.  You build a car using composition, not inheritance.

Comment: Has a seed is the definition of a fruit.

Comment: @paparazzo what about seedless grapes?

Comment: Is an Apple a fruit?  yes.  Is an apple a seed? no.  The seed is an apple factory, since it grows a tree to produce more apples.  An apple contains seeds and the cycle continues.  So back to what @RobertHarvey said.

Comment: @FirstLastname And seedless water melon.  Those are engineered fruits.

Comment: A common mistake is to attempt to model based on real life with no consideration of what you're actually modelling. You can't blindly say anything about whether it should be inheritance or composition without having an understanding of the actual model and how objects should interact with one another.

Comment: Is your actual question about how inheritance works, or the difference between 'is a' and 'has a' relations? Inheritance is an 'is a' relation, 'has a' relations are modeled by composition/containment.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? It might be a novice question, but still a relevant question to understand software engineering principles.

Comment: I would put it even more strongly, saying that inheritance can be determined using purely objective, deterministic processes, by examining the potential to share code or data. Abstract questions about inheritance without any details are not going to produce good answers.

Comment: @DirkBoer: askers on this site are expected to do some research on their own before asking, and tell us what they tried and why it did not suit their needs. This question, however, does not show any research effort (and that is exactly what tool tip on the downvote button starts with). And if you read the accepted answer, it basically says that pathological examples don't really help to understand software engineering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would be one way to represent the relationship, but this sounds like almost a classical case for composition over inheritance.  Going from the description alone, Apple could be a Fruit that contains a Seed.

However, there's only so much you can say from class names alone.  Program architecture being based off the real-world relation of the concepts involved is often used an example, but in practice the code should be designed based on how it will be used.  Something should be derived when it's desirable to be able to use instances of it interchangeably with the parent, not just because the concepts are taxonomically related IRL.

Comment: Technically, the seeds are what biologically separates fruits from veggies.  I know hair splitting.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we say Apple is inherited from Fruit and Seed?

I would suggest to consider better example/s if you trying to understand inheritance or composition concepts. If you already understand them then also understand that `Apple` can not really be a class in first place. Yes it "is-a" fruit but technically you would just create an instance of fruit and name it as apple. So the class you need is `Fruit` and not `Apple`, unless you are convinced that `Apple` can really have a specialized form which cannot be abstracted into `Fruit`.

```
class Fruit 
{
   string Name;
   string Color;
   bool Seedless;
   ...
}
```

And various fruits:

```
var apple = new Fruit { Name = "Apple", Seedless = false }
var grape = new Fruit { Name = "Grape", Seedless = true }
```

This is just like you defining a `Person` class and work with `wuzzu` and `nikhil` instances of it if you wanted to refer both of us.

If you are not convinced with having just a `Fruit` you can further consider defining specialized forms of `Fruit` based on fruit categories. Say,

```
class Berry : Fruit // ex: grape, banana
class Pome : Fruit // ex: apple, pear
// and so on.
```